# Domain Driven Design: cross domain

Tags: domain-driven-design

In DDD, how to mix repositories ?

For example, a simple social network app where a personn write a post and mention someone.

Do the best way is to check if "the mentioned person" exist in **user domain** and throw a event for **post domain** for example ?

I think there are a lot of examples when a API need to mix domain.
I had read some article which explains to use event system.
Is the only solution ? I'm not looking for the best solution or a "pure ddd app".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no such thing as a "pure ddd app".
DDD is architecturally agnostic. There's no architectural style you must follow. It will only depends on the domain complexity of the context you're working on. For example, don’t be afraid to go with a CRUD‐style architecture if you are dealing with a  context that contains no logic. Doing so, you'll be more in a DDD mindset than trying to apply things like Hexagonal/Onion/CQRS/EventSourcing and whatever good-looking architecture styles everywhere.

What you're describing in your question above is only related to the *tactical* part of DDD: what kind of code pattern would be nice to implement in order to solve my problem?

Let's say you have 2 different Bounded Context (see *Stategic* Patterns in DDD). One that deals with `Users` and one with `Posts`, as you mentioned above. As those are two separate contexts, they could have their own storage. In the `Posts` context, you could store a list of valid `UserIDs` that people can use when they want to mention someone. That way, you don't have to call any APIs to be sure that this `UserID` can be mentioned. In order to maintain this list, you also have many options. One could be to `listen` to events triggered by the `Users` context like `UserSuscribed` or `UserUnsubscribed`. Another option would be to give the responsibility to the `Users` context to call an API on the `Posts` context in order to add or delete `UsersIDs`.

In general, try to avoid coupling between your Bounded Contexts.

Comment: If Post and User are in same database, how to store "a list of valid UserIDs" ?

Comment: If both bounded context are sharing the same data in the same storage and they can both modify it, well, they're not really bounded context :) I'm not saying that it should be 2 different contexts, I'm just refering to your question where you said that `Posts` and `Users` were to separated domains.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'm learning DDD, I don't understand everything very well (bounded context domains...) thanks:)

Comment: That's cool to learn more about DDD :) Here's a link that might help: https://github.com/ddd-crew/welcome-to-ddd